# Quantity increase by 2, not one. Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have implemented a function, that increase the cart count by one, when you buy the same product, bt when I click the button it increases by 2 not 1

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{movieId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public int addItem(@PathVariable(value = "movieId") int movieId,@AuthenticationPrincipal User activeUser){


    Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerByUsername(activeUser.getUsername());
    Cart cart = customer.getCart();
    Movie movie = movieService.getMovieById(movieId);
    List<CartItem> cartItems = cart.getCartItems();


    for (CartItem item : cartItems) {
        if(movie.getMovieId()==item.getMovie().getMovieId()){
            CartItem cartItem = item;          
            cartItem.setQuantity(cartItem.getQuantity()+1);
            cartItem.setTotalPrice(movie.getMoviePrice()*cartItem.getQuantity());
            cartItemService.addCartItem(cartItem);

            return 0;
        }
    }

    CartItem cartItem = new CartItem();
    cartItem.setMovie(movie);
    cartItem.setQuantity(1);
    cartItem.setTotalPrice(movie.getMoviePrice()*cartItem.getQuantity());
    cartItem.setCart(cart);
    cartItemService.addCartItem(cartItem);

    return 0;

}
```

Angular Part

```
$scope.addToCart = function (movieId){
    $http.put("/rest/cart/add/"+movieId).success(function(){
         alert("Movie successfully add to the cart");
     });
};
```

HTML Button

```
<button class="btn btn-rose btn-round" ng-controller="cartCtrl" ng-click="addToCart('${movie.movieId}')">Add to Cart &nbsp;<i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i></button>
```

Comment: Seems we also need to know about `cartItemService`. But I guess that the statement `cartItemService.addCartItem(cartItem);` inside the `if` must be removed as the cart item is already there.

Comment: You never removed the item out of the cart, but then you put in the cart currentQuantity+1, which means if he had one movie in already, you add +2.
You could remove the item first and then add it with currentQuantity+1. As we can't see your cartItemService, please may try to have 5 movies in your cart already, then call your addItem(), after this, you probably have 11 items in your cart (5before + 5+1)

Comment: Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory:

Override
public void addCartItem (CartItem cartItem){

Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession ();
session.saveOrUpdate (cartItem) : 
session. flush();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that `for` you are trying to find movie with same id and than increase quantity of this, so why you run `cartItemService.addCartItem(cartItem)`? You should change it to update entity, something like `cartItemService.updateCartItem(cartItem)`.

Comment: Can you post your Entity class for CartItem?